# Can't add a new view in a storyboard without getting an not key value compliant message

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I'm getting the "not key-value coding compliant message".

I've had this several times in the past and know what it means and have always been able to resolve it, but I don't know why I'm getting it in this instance. All I've done is:
1) drag n drop a UILabel onto the main view:

[image]

2) Drag from the UILabel to view controller and get IB to insert and connect an outlet:
[image]

But when I run I get "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key currentStatus.'"

Here's the connections:

[image]
[image]

Why is it not working, what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown is ok, check if you removed some outlet properties from your code file (.h) and forgot to remove their links from IB.

Comment: No there no old links from IB. In fact when I couldn't solve the issue I deleted everything in IB and created a new VC with label from scratch in case Xcode/IB had got itself twisted. But the issue remains, its not just the UILabel, its anything, i.e. if I add anything at all to the storyboard I get the error message for whatever new I add.

Comment: can you upload your project or a sample so that I can fix that.

Comment: Sorry its full of company code, and it'd take a while to try and recreate a redacted sample version. However there's something possibly  pertinent I forgot to mention - the view controllers are in a static library while the storyboard is in a project that links to the library. I've used this pattern before without any issues.

Comment: I solved it - by adding the view controller .m file to the copy files section in build phases.